# How can I give myself access to the resolved value of a previous promise in a chain?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I have a route in express where I want to perform a bunch of async operations, then add some data to the database if certain conditions are met. So far, it looks like this (index.js):

```
router.post('/distributor/:id/upload', upload.single('file'), function 
(err,req, res, next ) { 
  if (err) { 
    console.log(req);
    console.log(req.file);
    console.error(err);
    return res.sendStatus(500);
  }
  next()
}, function (req, res, next) {  
    // console.log(req.file);
    csv()
      .fromFile(req.file.path)
      .subscribe((json)=>{ 
        // console.log(json)
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
          let product = new Item(json.Title); 
          product.distributor_id = req.params.id 
          product.SKU = json.SKU 
          product.UPC = json.UPC 
          product.Price = json.Price 
          return resolve(product) 
    }).then((product) => {
      // console.log(product) 
      //async request to external API
      var productInfo = getPriceandASIN.getPriceandASIN(product.UPC) 
      return productInfo
    }).then((info) => {  
      console.log(info) 
      console.log(product) 
      //a bunch of other stuff I don't need to worry about yet
      // return res.end()
    })
  });
})
```

If I just console.log(info), I get the expected response, the result of calling the previous async function for each item in the collection. However, if I also try to console.log(product), the whole function breaks, and I just get the info for the first item in the collection (and not the product), and nothing else. What is causing this behavior? I think there is something I am fundamentally not understanding about resolving promises, but I cannot tell what from the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "product" variable to be dereferenced in the function that you're calling `console.log(product)` in, so the basics of programming apply: if you want to access a thing, make that thing accessible. In this case, make the previous handler `return` all the data you need. If that's one var, return one var. If it's multiple vars, return an object with all of them:

```
  ...
  }).then(product => {
    var productInfo = await getPriceandASIN.getPriceandASIN(product.UPC);
    return { product, productInfo };
  }).then(data => {  
    console.log(data.productInfo);
    console.log(data.product);
    // ...
  })
});
```

Comment: I tried that, but since productInfo is an async function, it logs (promise <pending>) for info

Comment: You just `await` anything that uses `async`. The code in the answer has it for your `var productInfo`, but see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await for all the details and plenty of examples.

Comment: Okay I see now. Thanks!